# JavaME (PBP): How do I rotate text?

Tags: java, java-me, awt, graphics2d

How can I paint rotated text in JavaME ([Personal Basis Profile](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/pbp1.1.2/jsr217/index.html))?

Answer (score 1):

use j2me polish , see [Example](http://www1.j2mepolish.org/docs/gui-texteffect-rotating.html)

or this is [Example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/graphics2D/text-like-curve.shtml) using paint(Graphics g) method

Comment: The paint examples won't work (because affine transformations are not available in PBP), but +1 for j2me polish.